# python как корректно заполнить основной словарь с помошью цикла другими словарями

Tags: python-3.x, for, dict, enum

Чет потерялся совсем, вроде бы просто по ключу добавляем значения и все.
У меня выходит что в основной словарь добавляются ключи/значения: т.е ключи меняются, но вот значения в виде словаря(inner_dict) не меняются :/
Кратко: в цикле for хотел заполнить основной словарь base_dict, но данные для ключей base_dict сохраняются одни и те же

```
# key_val = {простой словарь вида: key: value ...}
inner_dict = {"type_sport": "", "player_1": "", "player_2": ""}
base_dict = {}

for i, value in enumerate(key_val):

    inner_dict["type_sport"] = value['SE']
    inner_dict["player_1"] = value['O1E']
    inner_dict["player_2"] = value['O2E']

    print(inner_dict)         # данные/словарь меняется т.е итерируется правильно
    base_dict[str(value['CI']) + str(i)] = inner_dict   # но некорректно сохраняются, а точнее 
                                                        # все значения для разных ключей словаря 
                                                        # base_dict одинаковые, как будто 
                                                        # inner_dict не обновляется
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from loguru import logger


url = 'https://melbet.ru/line/'

params = (
    ('count', '50'),
    ('tf', '1000000'),
    ('mode', '4'),
    ('cyberFlag', '4'),
    ('partner', '195'),
)

response = requests.get('https://melbet.ru/LineFeed/Get1x2_VZip', params=params)

champs = url.split('/')[-2].split('-')[0]     # разбиваем строку
# logger.info(f"{champs=}")

result = response.json()
# logger.info(f"{result=}")

key_val = result['Value']       # get base datas from json(server)
# logger.info(f"\n\n{key_val}")

inner_dict = {"full_url": '', "type_stake": "", "type_sport": "", "name_liga": "",
              "player_1": "", "player_2": "", "date_value": "", "P1": "", "X": "", "P2": "", "time_update": ""}
base_dict = {}

# j = 0

for i, value in enumerate(key_val):
    # logger.info(f" {i=}, {value['CI']=}, \n\n{value['E'][:3]}")
    # j += 1

    inner_dict["full_url"] = url
    inner_dict["type_stake"] = champs
    inner_dict["type_sport"] = value['SE']
    inner_dict["name_liga"] = value['LE']
    inner_dict["player_1"] = value['O1E']
    inner_dict["player_2"] = value['O2E']
    inner_dict["P1"] = value['E'][:3][0]['C']
    inner_dict["X"] = value['E'][:3][1]['C']
    inner_dict["P2"] = value['E'][:3][2]['C']

    base_dict[str(value['CI']) + str(i)] = inner_dict  # добавляю новый 
                                           # ключ с новым значением/словарем

    logger.info(f"{inner_dict=}\n")

    # logger.info(f"{base_dict=}\n")
    if i == 2:
        break

logger.info(f"\n{base_dict=}")
```

[image: итоговый результат должен выглядеть так]

Comment: В чём суть вопроса?

Comment: как заполнить/сохранить словарь корреткно и значения в виде словаря(inner dict) были в основном словаре base_dict были разными как и в цикле inner_dict обновляется/итерируется, но не сохраняется в основном словаре

Comment: Поясните, что вы хотите добиться циклом? Предоставьте исходные данные и то, что должно получиться в итоге.

Comment: ок набросаю сейчас

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это типовая ошибка начинающих питонистов - вы везде используете **один и тот же объект**, наполняя его разным содержанием. Поскольку это **один объект**, при изменении его содержимого, везде, где вы его использовали, отображаются эти изменения, поскольку везде у вас использована ссылка **на один и тот же словарь**. Не нужно экономить на таких вещах: **создавайте новый словарь**, а не переиспользуйте старый:

```
for i, value in enumerate(key_val):

    # создаём новый словарь на каждой итерации цикла
    inner_dict = {"full_url": '', "type_stake": "", "type_sport": "", "name_liga": "",
                  "player_1": "", "player_2": "", "date_value": "", "P1": "", "X": "", "P2": "", "time_update": ""}

    inner_dict["full_url"] = url
    inner_dict["type_stake"] = champs
    ...
```

Если вам нужно сохранить какие-то значения из предыдущего словаря - скопируйте их в переменные, а потом в новый словарь.

Ну либо есть вариант - делать копию словаря на каждой итерации цикла.

```
for i, value in enumerate(key_val):

    # создаём копию словаря
    inner_dict = inner_dict.copy()

    inner_dict["full_url"] = url
    inner_dict["type_stake"] = champs
    ...
```

Так тоже будет работать, но в общем случае лучше не делать копию, а создавать каждый раз новый объект. Просто лучше, если вы сразу запомните такую практику - обязательно создавать новые объекты, она позволит избежать ошибок в будущем.

Comment: Спасибо Вам,  все понял :)